# Rhino Javascript coverage using Debugger

Tags: code-coverage, rhino

I'm executing some Javascript inside Rhino, and wanted to have coverage data. I read in many places that implementing Debugger gives access to single line execution, and in fact the interface has a proper callback for it.

I'm planning to write my Debugger implementation to create coverage data.

However, I cannot find anywhere a similar implementation, and it seems strange to me that nobody used such a feature. Even systems that use Rhino and do coverage does not use that approach, but instrument javascript code instead.

Are you aware of :

1. Any existing Rhino Debugger implementation that does coverage analysis? Even just a proof of concept, or example code.
2. Any reason why such approach is not used? Will it be slow, will it introduce malfunctioning?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe try Mozilla or Rhino forums.